# Determining if a set is a subspace under unique circumstance

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a set of vector $C = \{ (d^2, e^2, f^2) \mid d,e,f \in R \}$, and need to show that it spans $R^3$.

I understand 3 conditions of a set being a subspace from class:

1. It must contain the zero point.
2. It must be closed under scalar multiplication and addition.
3. It must be the solution set of a homogenous linear system.

In my other simpler questions, I had always made sure that the vectors satisfy the condition, in this case is  $d,e,f \in R$. But must the result continue to satisfy $(d^2, e^2, f^2)$ as well?

While I am on this topic, I would also like to enquire about point 3. All my professor told us was that, if I solve a homogeneous system and from it, the solution is a non-trivial solution, that could be the linear span, which implies the solution space of the system. But will it ever occur such that we will need to figure out the original linear system based on the final parametric expression alone? If so, how can I go about it? I hope my question makes sense, I'm struggling slightly with the concepts. If this question doesn't make sense please feel free to ignore it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean to show the span of the vectors in $C$ is $\Bbb R^3$. By definition, the span of vectors is a subspace, so you don't need to prove that. You need to show it contains three linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to show that $C$ is a subspace ! $C$ is not a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3.$

You have to show that $span C= \mathbb R^3.$ To this end observe that

$$(1,0,0),(0,1,0), (0,0,1) \in C.$$